# PostgreSQL10, Pgcrypto, HMAC, how to recalculate data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, hmac, pgcrypto

I have to make cookies with a Hash created with the HMAC function for automatic authentication.

I was searching the internet how to use the HMAC function, and according to what I found, they do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   APP.USER
WHERE  ENCODE( HMAC( USER_ID::TEXT, 'MY_KEY', 'SHA256'), 'HEX') = COOKIE_HASH;
```

The problem is that postgres is doing a sequential scan. O (n)

I want to know if there is any way to retrieve the user_id with the key, in order to do a index scan.

- hmac documentation:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html
- hmac arguments: hmac(data text, key text, type text) returns bytea

Thanks for your time (forgive my english).

Answer (score 2):

Because your sql trying to run function on every rows. You can use functional index or save hashed and encoded value on another column.

Functional index:

```
CREATE INDEX fxix_user_id ON APP.USER(ENCODE(HMAC( USER_ID::TEXT, 'MY_KEY', 'SHA256'), 'HEX'));
```